# Multiple screen android presentation

Tags: android, multiple-monitors, presentation

I have an android app on a POS device with 2 screens.

I successfully start the app and put the customer totals screen on the second screen using this code:

```
displayManager =  (DisplayManager)getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
        if (displayManager!= null){
            presentationDisplays = displayManager.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION);
            if (presentationDisplays.length > 0){
                secondaryDisplay = new SecondaryDisplay(MainActivity.this, presentationDisplays[0]);
                secondaryDisplay.show();
            }
        }
```

The problem is that when I start a new activity for example teller clicks cash sale button and it brings up the amount tendered activity it is also showing on the second presentation screen.

How do I launch new activities only on the main screen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "How do I launch new activities only on the main screen?" -- by and large, the best answer probably is to get rid of the activities. Modern Android architecture is leaning *very* strongly towards having few activities, with differing screens behind handled by smaller units (fragments now, composables from Jetpack Compose in the future).

Comment: Thanks. Changed to DialogFragment and all worked

Answer (score 0):

As per above comment from CommonsWare switched to Fragment and it was on ly on the main screen